# Что означает двоеточие в командах shell?

Tags: linux, shell, zsh

Иногда встречаю команду `:` (двоеточие) в командах sh, например:

```
: | echo "hello"
```

Команда выше успешно выполнится и отобразит `hello`.

Для команды `:` нет справочной страницы, а если попытаться узнать её путь с помощью `which :`, то получим

> :: shell built-in command

Что означает это двоеточие и для чего оно используется?

Comment: `man $SHELL`, наверное, надо смотреть.

Answer (score 13):

справку об этой встроенной команде можно прочитать командой

```
$ help :
```

чаще всего эту команду можно встретить в таких конструкциях:

1. как короткую и экономичную замену программе *true*:

   1. в бесконечных циклах:

      ```
      while :; do ... done
      ```

      вместо:

      ```
      while true; do ... done
      ```
   2. в рецептах *makefile*-ов, если требуется игнорировать ненулевой код возврата команды:

      ```
        команда_код_возврата_которой_не_важен || :
      ```

      вместо:

      ```
        команда_код_возврата_которой_не_важен || true
      ```

      или вместо:

      ```
        -команда_код_возврата_которой_не_важен
      ```
2. когда надо передать вызываемой программе/команде пустую строку на её *stdin*:

   ```
   $ : | программа_ожидающая_получения_информации_на_stdin
   ```

   например:

   ```
   $ : | openssl s_client ...
   ```

Answer (score 10):

Двоеточие — это эквивалент операции "NOP" (no op, нет операции) (пустая команда). Может рассматриваться как синоним встроенной команды `true`. Команда `:` также является встроенной командой Bash, которая всегда возвращает `true` (0).

Comment: Нет, не эквивалент. NOP ничего не делает, ничего не возвращает и ничего не изменяет по определению.